# administer MSSQL databases from Drupal 6

Tags: 6, database

Can you advise on a way to manage my SQL Server databases from Drupal 6x. I am using SQL Server for PHP driver (i.e. `sqlsrv_connect()`) to connect to my databases. Is there any module I could use to administer my databases?

If any more information about my query is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for MSSQL Server in Drupal 6, so it is higly unlikely that a module that can help you to administer your MSSQL databases exists.

You could maybe write your own, see [MSSql or SQL Server Wrapper for custom module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1631/mssql-or-sql-server-wrapper-for-custom-module) for a possible way to connect to your database while still being able to rely on some API's provided by Drupal.

Comment: Thank you Berdir for your quick response! I shall look into what you mentioned... Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I am also connecting to sql server from drupal, and here is what I've learned on my blog http://www.barnettech.com/taxonomy/term/28  It describes what to install on the linux box to run queries and stored procs.  You need to create custom modules to make calls to sql server from within Drupal.  In my case I made my own services to add on to the services module.

Comment: Thank you for the advice user1246! I shall look into what you suggested